# Функция readLine() не считывает информацию

Tags: kotlin, ввод

Тестировал свой код на https://play.kotlinlang.org/ и https://developer.android.com/training/kotlinplayground, в обоих случаях в переменную `stringInput` записывается значение `null`. Помогите разобраться, почему `readLine()` не считывает строку, которую вводит компилятор сайта.

Код:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    println("Камень-ножницы-бумага на kotlin!")
    println("1 - камень, 2 - ножницы, 3 - бумага")
    print("Ваш выбор:")
    val stringInput = readLine()// код ввода информации
    println(stringInput)
}
```

Вывод программы:

```
Камень-ножницы-бумага на kotlin!
1 - камень, 2 - ножницы, 3 - бумага
Ваш выбор:null
```

Comment: Данные сайты не подразумевают ввода через stdin, на https://play.kotlinlang.org/ ещё можно через аргументы командной строки (они будут в arr `fun main(arr: Array<String>)` )

Comment: Можно поподробнее?

Comment: У веб-песочницы нет консоли в том виде, в каком `readLine()` ожидает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй использовать Scanner.
`readline` зачастую работает только в консоли.

```
val scanner = Scanner(System.in)
val stringInput = scanner.nextLine()
```